# 'input string not in a correct format' with a null value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a button that adds the values of multiple labels(that are filled with currency values) and displays the sum in another label.

```
decimal[] totals = new decimal[11]; 

    private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totals[0] = decimal.Parse(lblText1.Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
        totals[1] = decimal.Parse(lbltext2.Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
        lbltotal.Text = totals.Sum().ToString("C");
    }
```

Works fine until one is empty and I get 'input string not in a correct format'.

Comment: what do you expect? what should be decimal value for ""?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't bother calling if the text is empty
2. Use decimal.TryParse

Comment: When I input the arguments for TryParse I get 'cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'decimal'.